# Virtual audio splitter?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I want to split audio coming from a program into 2 usable streams. One for being able to listen to, and one for directing audio into Discord's microphone input for streaming because discord doesn't support audio streaming on linux yet. How can I achieve this using pulseaudio? I've been looking at the docs but I haven't found anything that seems like it would work.